android - simulate stack memory leak
I would like to simulate a stack memory leak. The stack means the value list in as dumpsys meminfo com.sample.demo (428Kb in below sample):
 App Summary
                       Pss(KB)                        Rss(KB)
                        ------                         ------
           Java Heap:     8016                          30776
         Native Heap:     6428                          10600
                Code:    21784                          86164
               Stack:      428                            440
            Graphics:     5268                           5268
       Private Other:     2972
              System:     4370
             Unknown:                                    7384
 
           TOTAL PSS:    49266            TOTAL RSS:   140632      TOTAL SWAP (KB):     3432


I have try to use new ArrayList<>(); but it allocate memory in Java category.

Create an infinite recursive function and trigger it:
private void call() {
    call();
}

To increase the frame size, allocate some primitives in the function. Also, the app most likely will be killed with a StackOverflow exception - so add a counter and check it before calling the function.

Good idea, I try it and in android, it report OutOfMemory instead of stackoverflow.
